# Verificar se um valor existe no Realtime Database do Firebase

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, firebase, realtime-database

Eu tenho um banco de dados com essa estrutura:

[image: árvore de dados do banco]

o que acontece é que ao criar um usuário novo, eu preciso verificar se já não existe um nickname igual cadastrado, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Aqui está o código que está dando errado, com alguns comentários do que eu acho que deveria estar certo:

```
if (edtCadSenha.getText().toString().equals(edtCadConfirmaSenha.getText().toString())) {
                referencia = ConfiguracaoFirebase.getFirebase();
                //nessa linha, é definida a ordem de busca. no laço usuarios procurando por
                //resultados onde o nick digitado pelo usuário seja igual a algum já cadastrado
                //e, adicionando .limitToFirst(1), limita o número de resultados necessários
                //para terminar a execução a um só.
                Query buscaNick = referencia.child("usuarios").orderByChild("nickname").equalTo(edtCadNickname.getText().toString()).limitToFirst(1);
                buscaNick.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //se cair aqui, significa que encontrou um nick igual

                        Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Esse nick já existe, escolha outro por favor!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //se caiu aqui, significa que não tem um nick igual no bd, então
                        //o usuário pode seguir o cadastro normalmente.
                        usuarios = new Usuarios();
                        //recupera todos os valores nos campos preenchidos na tela pelo usuário
                        //e armazena no objeto de usuário
                        usuarios.setNome(edtCadNome.getText().toString());
                        usuarios.setNickname(edtCadNickname.getText().toString());
                        usuarios.setEmail(edtCadEmail.getText().toString());
                        usuarios.setSenha(edtCadSenha.getText().toString());
                        usuarios.setAniversario(edtCadAniversario.getText().toString());
                        //faz a checagem de qual botão de radio está selecionado para preencher o campo sexo
                        if (rbFeminino.isChecked()) {
                            usuarios.setSexo("Feminino");
                            cadastrarUsuario();
                        } else if(rbMasculino.isChecked()) {
                            usuarios.setSexo("Masculino");
                            cadastrarUsuario();
                        }
```

No exemplo, a query só cai no primeiro exemplo, e mostra a mensagem de "Esse nick já existe"

Answer (score 1):

Beleza gurizada?
Segue como "fazer a comparacao", neste caso, eu tentei buscar um email ja existente dentro da minha tabela de usuarios. Para isso, fiz uma query organizada pelo email que compara o que eu passei no MaterialEditText (pode ser qualquer string) com o resultado da Query feita. Veja:

```
public void validateEmail(){
    Query buscaEmail = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
            .orderByChild("email")
            .equalTo(metEmail.getText().toString());

    buscaEmail.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            /* Getting users if exists using the email provided as key*/
            if(!snapshot.exists()) {
                makeSignUp();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "Este email ja esta cadastrado.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            Toast.makeText(signUp.this, "Algum erro ocorreu!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

No caso em na criacao da Query buscaEmail, eu fiz a referencia a tabela usuario com o `getReference("User")` ordenada por email e depois comparado com o texto do MaterialEditText que usei.
Logo depois fiz o EventListener, creio que essa parte voce ja deva conhecer, entao vou apenas para o importante: Na query, caso haja um snapshot, significa que houve um retorno da sua query, entao logo depois apenas verifiquei se existia o snapshot com `if(!snapshot.exists())` no meu caso nao podia existir para continuar a cadastrar.
Espero ter ajudado.

*"Update sem Where e uma obrigacao do estagiario"* - **O Estagiario.**

Answer (score -1):

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) { 

          If(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    //se cair aqui, significa que encontrou um nick igual

                    Toast.makeText(CadastroActivity.this, "Esse nick já 
                         existe, escolha outro por favor!", 
                 Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              }else{
                      Continue...........
               }
  }
```